# How can I vertically align all the content including borders in the columns?

Tags: html, css, grid, vertical-alignment, css-tables

Please see codepen for reference: http://codepen.io/rezasan/pen/apvMOR

I'm trying to make all the contents in the columns (Date, Title and Button even the separator to be vertically aligned. Tried display table but doesn't work. Require some assistance from the experts here.

HTML:

```
    <ul class="ir_home_news">                 
        <li class="si_fixed">
            <div class="ir_home_newsDate">18 November 2016</div>
            <div class="ir_home_newsTitle">Disclosure Of Interest</div>
            <div class="ir_home_button"><a href=""><button>VIEW DETAILS</button></a></div>
        </li>
        <li class="si_fixed">
            <div class="ir_home_newsDate">18 November 2016</div>
            <div class="ir_home_newsTitle">Disclosure Of Interest</div>
            <div class="ir_home_button"><a href=""><button>VIEW DETAILS</button></a></div>
        </li>
        <li class="si_fixed">
            <div class="ir_home_newsDate">18 November 2016</div>
            <div class="ir_home_newsTitle">Disclosure Of Interest</div>
            <div class="ir_home_button"><a href=""><button>VIEW DETAILS</button></a></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
    ul,li{
      margin:0;
      padding:0
    }

    li{
      list-style-type:none;
    }
    .ir_home_news li{
      border-top:1px solid #ebebeb;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .ir_home_news li:nth-child(even){
      background-color: #f8f8f8;
    }

    .ir_home_news li::after {
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        display: table;
    }

    .ir_home_news li div{
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
      padding: 0px 15px;
      border-right: 1px solid red;
    }

    .ir_home_news li div:last-child{
      border-right: none;
    }

    .ir_home_newsDate {
      float: left;
      width: 18%;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      font-size: 18px;
      color:#003087;
    }

    .ir_home_newsTitle{
      float: left;
      width: 65%;
      font-size: 17px;
      color:#003087;
    }

    .ir_home_button{
      float: left;
      width: 10%;
    }
    .ir_home_button button{

      background-color: #003087;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 15px 25px;
      border-radius: 0;
      font-size: 13px;
    }
```

```css
 ul,
    li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0
    }
    
    li {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    
    .ir_home_news li {
        border-top: 1px solid #ebebeb;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .ir_home_news li:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #f8f8f8;
    }
    
    .ir_home_news li::after {
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        display: table;
    }
    
    .ir_home_news li div {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding: 0px 15px;
        border-right: 1px solid red;
    }
    
    .ir_home_news li div:last-child {
        border-right: none;
    }
    
    .ir_home_newsDate {
        float: left;
        width: 18%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #003087;
    }
    
    .ir_home_newsTitle {
        float: left;
        width: 65%;
        font-size: 17px;
        color: #003087;
    }
    
    .ir_home_button {
        float: left;
        width: 10%;
    }
    
    .ir_home_button button {
        background-color: #003087;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 15px 25px;
        border-radius: 0;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="ir_home_news">                 
            <li class="si_fixed">
                <div class="ir_home_newsDate">18 November 2016</div>
                <div class="ir_home_newsTitle">Disclosure Of Interest</div>
                <div class="ir_home_button"><a href=""><button>VIEW DETAILS</button></a></div>
            </li>
            <li class="si_fixed">
                <div class="ir_home_newsDate">18 November 2016</div>
                <div class="ir_home_newsTitle">Disclosure Of Interest</div>
                <div class="ir_home_button"><a href=""><button>VIEW DETAILS</button></a></div>
            </li>
            <li class="si_fixed">
                <div class="ir_home_newsDate">18 November 2016</div>
                <div class="ir_home_newsTitle">Disclosure Of Interest</div>
                <div class="ir_home_button"><a href=""><button>VIEW DETAILS</button></a></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not use `floar: left` inside your li, it will cause your **vertical-align** no worked,

```css
ul,
    li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0
    }
    
    li {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    
    .ir_home_news li {
        border-top: 1px solid #ebebeb;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .ir_home_news li:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #f8f8f8;
    }
    
    .ir_home_news li::after {
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        display: table;
    }
    
    .ir_home_news li div {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding: 0px 15px;
        border-right: 1px solid red;
    }
    
    .ir_home_news li div:last-child {
        border-right: none;
    }
    
    .ir_home_newsDate {
        width: 18%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #003087;
    }
    
    .ir_home_newsTitle {
        width: 65%;
        font-size: 17px;
        color: #003087;
    }
    
    .ir_home_button {
        width: 10%;
    }
    
    .ir_home_button button {
        background-color: #003087;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 15px 25px;
        border-radius: 0;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="ir_home_news">
        <li class="si_fixed">
            <div class="ir_home_newsDate">18 November 2016</div>
            <div class="ir_home_newsTitle">Disclosure Of Interest</div>
            <div class="ir_home_button">
                <a href="">
                    <button>VIEW DETAILS</button>
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="si_fixed">
            <div class="ir_home_newsDate">18 November 2016</div>
            <div class="ir_home_newsTitle">Disclosure Of Interest</div>
            <div class="ir_home_button">
                <a href="">
                    <button>VIEW DETAILS</button>
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="si_fixed">
            <div class="ir_home_newsDate">18 November 2016</div>
            <div class="ir_home_newsTitle">Disclosure Of Interest</div>
            <div class="ir_home_button">
                <a href="">
                    <button>VIEW DETAILS</button>
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I just remove all `float: left` inside your li

```
.ir_home_newsDate {
    width: 18%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #003087;
}

.ir_home_newsTitle {
    width: 65%;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #003087;
}

.ir_home_button {
    width: 10%;
}
```

Comment: I see. I missed out on that. So we can still align the columns without using float. Great. Thank you for your wonderful assistance. Much appreciated! It works.